# Check if an Image is set or has a picture in xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, image, xamarin.forms

Which property/method should I use to detect if the `Image` has a Picture attached to it or not?

I tried to use `IsSet()` but asks for an argument.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can just check if the source is null or not

Comment: Ok, let me use this approach.

Comment: @LutaayaHuzaifahIdris Is that source  null worked?

Comment: Nope it didn't @LeonLu-MSFT

Comment: I just use ` if(testImage.Source ==null)` it could be check the image is set or not, can you share related code?

Comment: Hey I used this condition, but it wasn't checked for, currently I had resorted to a different approach, does this work on your side? @LeonLu-MSFT

Comment: I can use it in my demo